# How to send a message outside the controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, .net-core-3.1

I need to send information to the connected clients outside the HUB.

**Here my class :**

```
public static class Notification{
  public static void SendMessage(){
    //... Do some stuff
    MyHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("sendInfo");
  }
}
```

How to instantiate HUB?

Comment: Hi @Mário Augusto de Freitas,did my reply help you? If my reply have already solved your issue, please accept it as answer. About how mark it as answer, you could refer to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This will help other people who faces the same issue..If not,could you please follow up to let me know?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you could use IHubContext service to send the service message outside the hub.

If you have register the service inside the ConfigureServices in startup.cs, then you could  access an instance of IHubContext via dependency injection.

```
        services.AddSignalR();
```

E.g Inject an instance of IHubContext in a controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

Now, with access to an instance of IHubContext, you can call hub methods as if you were in the hub itself.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Home page loaded at: {DateTime.Now}");
    return View();
}
```

More details ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

You do as @Brando Zhang posted above or just inject the Hub in to your controller or manager like:

Controller

```cs
private IHubContext<YourHub, IYourHub> YourHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<YourHub, IYourHub>>();
    }
}
```

Other

```cs
private IHubContext<YourHub, IYourHub> YourHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<YourHub, IYourHub>>();
    }
}
```

PS: It is recomended to inject the HubContext and not the hub directly.